# Can't consume avro data from Confluent Kafka topics to Hbase

Tags: apache-kafka, hbase, streaming, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I use below sample code to load some test data from Confluent Kafka to Hbase, but somehow I do not see data comes in Hbase. I tried everything but did not work at all. Anyone can help this?

How to duplicate the issue:

1. Download the Sample code:

https://github.com/mravi/kafka-connect-hbase

2. Compile the Sample code

   mvn -DskipTests=true package
3. Modified the hbase-sink.properties on ConnectDistributed servers

vim ./etc/kafka-connect-hbase/hbase-sink.properties

```
name=kafka-cdc-hbase
connector.class=io.svectors.hbase.sink.HBaseSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test
zookeeper.quorum=wdsjnl012.test.com:2181
event.parser.class=io.svectors.hbase.parser.AvroEventParser

hbase.test.rowkey.columns=id

hbase.test.rowkey.delimiter=,

hbase.test.family=name
```

4. Start ConnectDistributed by below command:

   ./bin/confluent start connect
5. Create Hbase table:

   hbase(main):007:0> create 'test','name'

   hbase(main):007:0> describe  'test'
   Table test is ENABLED
   test
   COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
   {NAME => 'name', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 
   'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_EN
   CODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => 
   '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536'
   , REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
6. produce data:

   ./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list wdsjnl010:9092 --topic test 
   --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"record","fields": 
   [{"name":"id","type":"int"}, {"name":"name", "type": "string"}]}'

   {"id": 1, "name": "foo"}

By the way, I double check hbase connect was loaded or not from log file , I think hbase connect plugin already loaded:

```
[2018-05-18 19:48:32,714] INFO Loading plugin from: 
/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-hbase 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-05-18 19:48:35,447] INFO Registered loader: 
PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka- 
connect-hbase/} 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-05-18 19:48:35,447] INFO Added plugin 
'io.svectors.hbase.sink.HBaseSinkConnector' 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-05-18 19:48:35,447] INFO Loading plugin from: 
/usr/local/confluent/share/java/confluent-common 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-05-18 19:48:35,516] INFO Registered loaded:
PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/confluent-common/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
    [2018-05-18 19:48:35,518] INFO Loading plugin from: /usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-s3 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:194)
[2018-05-18 19:48:38,396] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/usr/local/confluent/share/java/kafka-connect-s3/} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-05-18 19:48:38,396] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:146)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,673] INFO Registered loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:217)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,675] INFO Added aliases 'ElasticsearchSinkConnector' and 'ElasticsearchSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,675] INFO Added aliases 'HdfsSinkConnector' and 'HdfsSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,676] INFO Added aliases 'JdbcSinkConnector' and 'JdbcSink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,676] INFO Added aliases 'JdbcSourceConnector' and 'JdbcSource' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,676] INFO Added aliases 'S3SinkConnector' and 'S3Sink' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,676] INFO Added aliases 'HBaseSinkConnector' and 'HBaseSink' to plugin 'io.svectors.hbase.sink.HBaseSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,676] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSinkConnector' and 'FileStreamSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSourceConnector' and 'FileStreamSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'MockConnector' and 'Mock' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'MockSinkConnector' and 'MockSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'MockSourceConnector' and 'MockSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSinkConnector' and 'VerifiableSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,677] INFO Added aliases 'VerifiableSourceConnector' and 'VerifiableSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'AvroConverter' and 'Avro' to plugin 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'ByteArrayConverter' and 'ByteArray' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'JsonConverter' and 'Json' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'StringConverter' and 'String' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'ByteArrayConverter' and 'ByteArray' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'JsonConverter' and 'Json' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added alias 'SimpleHeaderConverter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,678] INFO Added aliases 'StringConverter' and 'String' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:351)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,680] INFO Added alias 'RegexRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,680] INFO Added alias 'TimestampRouter' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,680] INFO Added alias 'ValueToKey' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:348)
[2018-05-18 19:48:40,700] INFO DistributedConfig values:
```

Comment: There's not enough logging here I think to answer the question. Do you have more logging you can show? Specifically toward the end of the log for the connect worker process.